# Does Entity Framework or Telerik Data Access support DATA migrations? (NOT schema migrations)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, telerik, data-access-layer

The question in the title is pretty self-explanatory. Does either Entity Framework or Telerik Data Access support data migrations? I've searched for many combinations of the terms "data migration" "entity framework" and "telerik data access" without any luck.

Just to be clear, data migrations, in the context of this question, are similar to schema migrations. But instead of updating the schema, it updates the data contained within the tables. Data migrations do NOT change the schema, and therefore cannot be contained in EF's data models or Telerik's data models. Data migrations are also found in Rails and I'm trying to figure out if there's a similar concept in EF or Telerik Data Access.

If not, is there any other tool that supports data migrations? I know of SharpMigrations project (https://github.com/andrecarlucci/sharpmigrations) and I gave it a shot, but it seems like it's still in very early stages and definitely not a production-ready product. Tt only has 2 contributers as of this writing, and when I downloaded the latest version of the project, many of the tests are failing and the documentation is very lacking in terms of how to actually get it to work. And when I finally got to the point where it could have worked, it didn't work and threw errors even when I ran it exactly the way it's documented. If anyone knows of any other tool that facilitate data migrations, please enlighten me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the telerik [site](http://www.telerik.com/forums/data-migrations) it seems it currently does not support it.  But EF has some support for this - requires a bit of coding of course.  An article on how to do code first migrations is at this [URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) for automated build migrations and etc...  A quick search via google revealed many such blog post...

Hope this helps out...